# How to change slideWidth in bxSlider after creating?

Tags: javascript, bxslider

How to change slideWidth in bxSlider after creating? Standart bxSlider can't make right width of slides when viewport resizing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use adaptive height as telling in documentation http://bxslider.com/examples/slideshow-adaptive-height or change div size of your slider;

```
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
  adaptiveHeight: true,
  mode: 'fade'
});
```

changing div size of slider

```
<div style="height:500px;width:800px;">
  <ul class="bxslider">
    <li><img src="/images/730_200/hill_fence.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="/images/730_100/tree_root.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="/images/730_150/me_trees.jpg" /></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```